# Make an awk command faster

Tags: bash, performance, awk

file1.csv have 2.4 million rows with the following structure

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```

I making this file1.csv to have this structure

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```

After I m using the following a w k command

```
cat file1.csv | awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="," } {cmd = "./cfg/trim_script.sh "$2""; while ( ( cmd | getline rezultat ) > 0 ) { if (rezultat=="<NULL") {print $0","} else {print $0","rezultat} }  close(cmd);}'
```

with `trim_script.sh` defined as follows:

```
trimmed=`grep $1, file_for_use.txt | cut -d "," -f 2 | cut -d ">" -f 1 `
trimmed="${trimmed## }"
# Strip trailing space.
trimmed="${trimmed%% }"
```

file_for_use.txt has this structure

```
< 111111,product1 >
< 222222,product2 >
< 333333,<NULL >
```

My flow works with no problem. But this takes about 6 hours to process 2.4 million rows. Can someone help me make it faster? Cause now the awk command is processing row by row.
Something like 250 rows/second. Can I make some improvements here? For example something like getline rezultat "product1" to bulk print at all rows that have $2=="111111". I need somehow to
get rid of the row by row processing but to keep the same flow.

Thank you very much. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: The task in words is: join *file_for_use.txt*, column 1, with *file1.csv*, column 2?

Comment: Awk is fast if you use **native awk**, but as soon as you start a subprocess for every single line... I recommend forgetting that awk supports `cmd | ...` or anything else that runs a subprocess at all; just pretend the features never existed in the first place -- since using them defeats the benefits of using awk in the first place -- and write _native_ awk code instead.

Comment: (`trim_script.sh` is _also_ deeply inefficient, and the way you start it is seriously insecure; a filename that contains `$(rm -rf ~)` being passed to `trim_script` would cause your home directory to be deleted)

Comment: @AndreWildberg yes you are correct

Comment: Are you aware that there's a UNIX `join` command? It requires that both inputs be sorted by your key, which of course has a significant performance cost (`O(log n)` for each input or such, which with inputs larger than memory is done per-section with sections merged together at the end by contemporary GNU sort or such), but once that's done the actual join is `O(n+m)` and runs in constant memory.

Comment: Something like that? `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !seen[$2]++{print $2,$NF}' file1.csv`

Comment: I m no longer using the trim script. Should be ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you convert your `file_for_use.txt` into AWK file following way

```
< 111111,product1 >
< 222222,product2 >
< 333333,<NULL >
```

into say `convert.awk` as follows

```
BEGIN{FS=","}
$2=="111111"{print $0 "product1";next}
$2=="222222"{print $0 "product2";next}
{print}
```

and when `file1.csv` is

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```

usage is

```
awk -f convert.awk file1.csv
```

which gives output

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```

Note that as your `file_for_use.txt` was just few lines I created `convert.awk` manually editing you but if it is actually bigger you might use GNU `AWK` itself to create core of GNU `AWK` code, e.g. following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[<> ,]*"}!/NULL/{printf "$2==\"%s\"{print $0 \"%s\";next}\n",$2,$3}' file_for_use.txt
```

will output

```
$2=="111111"{print $0 "product1";next}
$2=="222222"{print $0 "product2";next}
```

Keep in mind to add first line and last line in your favorite text editor and this assumes that `<>` and space and comma never appear in number or name.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk  'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }

FNR==NR{
    gsub(/^<[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+>$/,"")
    if ($2~/NULL/) next
    db[$1]=$2
    next
}
# second file
$2 in db {$(NF)=db[$2]}
1
' file_for_use.txt file
```

Comment: Even without verifying that this is correct, +1 because inlining a trivial shell script into the `awk` script itself  does wonders by avoiding the execution of *millions* of external commands (the multiple invocations of `sh` to run the shell script, as well as the execution of `grep` and `cut`--twice!--by the shell).

Comment: @dawg : i thought the whole purpose of that `"<NULL"` is to signal an intentional replacement with an empty string `""`, in case there's any existing value in that column, and only entries not found in 1st file are allowed to retain any existing value, if any ? Otherwise, if the `"<NULL"` serves an identical role to "non-existing", then why bother having that entry in `file_in_use.txt` in the first place ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: Good questions, but without clarity from the OP anything is strictly speculation. As written here, it is easy to make the `"<NULL" anything appropriate to the solution desired.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the join field is made up of only numbers (`0-9`)
- the component from `file_for_use.txt` of interest (ie, to be appended to lines from `file1.csv`) is made up of only numbers (`0-9`) and letters (`a-zA-Z`)
- if `NULL` shows up in the 2nd field of the `file_for_use.txt` file, it is by itself (ie, we don't have to worry about strings like `productNULL` or `NOT_NULL` or `NULLbydesign`)

General design:

- make a single pass through each file
- scan `file_for_use.txt` first; remove extraneous characters and save the replacement mappings in the `awk` array `map[]`
- scan `files1.csv` second; if the 2nd field is an index in the `map[]` array then replace the last field (with the value from the `map[]` array) otherwise leave the last field alone

Modifying OP's input file sample:

```
$ cat file1.csv
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,replace this field
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,replace this field
7892343242,444444,,,,,0,,3,,,,,keep this field
8234234223,444444,,,,,0,,3,,,,,keep this field
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN    { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR  { gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",$1)           # remove all non-numbers from 1st field
           gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]|NULL/,"",$2)      # remove all non-numbers/non-letters, as well as string "NULL", from 2nd field
           map[$1]=$2                           # store what is left in the 2nd field in the array
           next
          }
$2 in map { $NF=map[$2] }
1
' file_for_use.txt file1.csv
```

This generates:

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
7892343242,444444,,,,,0,,3,,,,,keep this field
8234234223,444444,,,,,0,,3,,,,,keep this field
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, also removing "<NULL" in *file_for_use.txt*

```
% awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{f2[$1]=$2; next} {print $0""f2[$2]}
    ' <(awk '{sub(/<NULL/, "", $0); print $2}' file_for_use.txt) file1.csv
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're looking for dynamic code generation without being repetitive,

perhaps :

```
echo '
< 111111,product1 >
< 222222,product2 >
< 333333,<NULL >' |
```

> ```
>   mawk ' sub("<NULL",_, $!(NF = NF))^_' FS='^< *|,| *>$' \
>         OFS='" ? "'     ORS='" : $2=="' RS='^< *|[ >]+\n[ <]*' | 
>
>   mawk 'gsub("^[^:]+:[ ]*|[^:]+$",_) sub(".+", " $NF = & $NF")' RS='^$' ORS=
> ```

```
 $NF = $2=="111111" ? "product1" : $2=="222222" ? "product2" : $2=="333333" ? "" : $NF
```

The generator code itself is longer but you'll end up with one long chain of ternaries instead of new pattern-action block for every single condition

Answer (score -1):

but if u wanna KISS, then :

> ```
> mawk 'NR == FNR ? _*(__[$2] = "<NULL" == $3 ? "" : $3) \
>       : $2 in __==_ || ($NF = __[$2] )^_' OFS=',' FS='^< ?|,| ?>$'
> ```

```
1200162574,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2200166021,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200174555,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
4200214253,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
5200223369,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
6200272098,111111,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product1
2000162574,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
3000166021,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
4000174555,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
5000214253,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
6000223369,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
7000272098,222222,,,,,0,,3,,,,,product2
2231223369,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
5453454546,333333,,,,,0,,3,,,,,
```